# Access Master Page Variable From Content Page VB

Tags: vb.net, variables, code-behind

I am having some difficulty accessing a variable on on master page this is what I have got.

Site.Master.vb

```
Public Class Site
    Inherits System.Web.UI.MasterPage

    Public VarToSee As String = "TESTING THIS"

End Class
```

ContentPage.vb

```
Public Class ContentPage

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Msgbox(VarToSee)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The error I get "variable used before it has being assigned a value"
Basically it can't see it.

Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the class for your content page does not inherit the class for your master page.

If you want to get the master page from your content page you have can get it from the `Page.Master` property

If you want to reference a field or property specific to that MasterPage class you have to cast it first. Like this: `CType(Me.Master, Site)`

so it would end up looking like this:

```
Public Class ContentPage

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim FooVar As String = CType(Me.Master, Site).VarToSee
        Msgbox(FooVar)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: what is the variable site?

Comment: its not a variable, it's the type that you are casting too. In the example, Kiel made a class called "Site" which is an extension of the "MasterPage" class type. The property "Me.Master" holds a "MasterPage" object, which is fine because it's a wider type than "Site" but we have to cast it back into a "Site" object to access the properties specific to it